# Microsoft Access Number Formatting Error

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2010, number-formatting

This is my customer format: `"MVR "#,##0.00`.
But when I enter a number like `100,000,000` it displays like this: `#########`.

How can I correct this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This normally is a problem with the width of the Text Box you are using, try expanding the width of the control.

Comment: And might I add, PaulFrancis, under the Access / Options (via Backstage for Access 2010 and 2013), in the Current Database tab if you remove the check for 'Check for truncated number fields', the '###' will no longer display. This includes all objects (tables, forms, queries, reports).